# Get the list of all site collections where add-in is deployed via tenant scope deployment

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom, tenant-scope-deployment

We can do batch installation of SharePoint add-in by installing the add-in to tenant app catalog and then select deployment from app menu (in classic view) which will redirect us to "DeployTSApp.aspx"

Here we are provided with multiple options how we can do the batch installation of our app

1. Provide a list of custom site collection, where you want to deploy the app
2. Provide managed path
3. Provide site template

Can we fetch this saved information somehow in CSOM?

Or any other way in CSOM, where I can get the list of site collection where app is deployed tenant scoped?